# Guidance needed to develop an hybrid mobile app

Tags: iphone, html, ios, ipad, uiwebview

i have an existing iPhone and android application. my goal is to make some component in thsese apps reusable. so i am identifying components which are not using device capabilities and then will design these components from HTML pages so that the same code will be used in both apps.

one more requirement is that whatever web service is being used , that will be called from objective C or Java code and response will be consumed in my Html page.

Please give me your ideas as how can i achieve it? 
what all tools should i use to make these pages?
are there any challenges, that we need to face at any stage in development?

I have no idea of web site development and html technologies, that's why i am looking for a help here.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Rather than have bits of native and bits of HTML you would be better to develop the entire thing in [Phonegap](http://phonegap.com). Phonegap is developed in HTML and JS and then compiled into a native app utilising the OS's web view. This means that you will have the exact same code across devices and will allow for a more consistent UI.

Phonegap allows for native device functions to be used such as geolocation, accelerometer, audio, video, notifications, storage and more.

Comment: thanks for the answer james
actually these are already existing application and developing these application from scratch will impact the budget. we just want to develop the reusable components. these components doesn't use device capability. these ui are just for read purpose and simple table row add/remove functionality and we display data from web services. we need to call these web services from native code only

Answer (score 0):

use [Jquery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/) to develop user interface and to package it as a offline app use [phonegap.com](http://phonegap.com/)

Hope it Helps !!!

Comment: Helo Zia, thanks for the answer.
As i said in above comment on james post, we just need to redevelop only few components in existing app and rest everything will remain in  native code. u can check my question again for detail.

Comment: dear vikas , your app have two parts UI and Webservices right! i am saying use jquerymobile to redo your UI part and call your existing webservice as it is from the new UI!